# Chicane router: Suitable type to represent a route object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, router, chicane

When using [Chicane router](https://swan-io.github.io/chicane), is there a suitable type that can represent a route object that can be passed between components?

For instance, how would `Route` be defined below?

```js
function doSomething(route: Route) {
  Router.push(route)
}
```

I'm imagining a `Route` would be a tuple like: `["CustomerDetails", { id: 123 }]`